# Nvidia GT 640 Issues

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I've recently installed Ubuntu, and my mouse is extremely laggy. I have attempted using multiple mice, some wired, others wireless, but to no avail. Turning off 3D Ubuntu on the log on screen doesn't help at all.

A few weeks later I installed TF2 to see if it would run well in Ubuntu. Unfortunately the game lags on the menu, and the graphics were automatically set to low (very rough, pixel-y edges).

I've currently got the Beta driver 3.10 (I'm pretty sure its the one Steam insists I install over the others) on my Nvidia GT 640.

My specs are:

Intel i5 2320 @ 3.00GHz

Gigabyte 2GB DDR3 GT 640

DZ77BH-55K Intel Motherboard

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit) dual-booted alongside Windows 8 (64-bit).
The UEFI is disabled and the motherboard uses BIOS instead (the people who built this computer knew what they were doing!).

Am I using the open source or official drivers?
How can I fix this?
Is Ubuntu using the integrated graphics on the processor instead of the graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

By default you are greeted with the Open Source Nouveau driver (If the Nvidia is installed). If you remove the Nvidia card it will default to the Intel video card inside the processor. The Nvidia Nouveau driver is not bad, but for video cards as powerful as yours you need the Proprietary Drivers. in you case you need to follow the steps I provided in this question: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/newest-nvidia-card-what-driver-should-i-install/61433#61433)

Since your motherboard is basically awesome (All DZ77 are awesome!) and had the option to disable UEFI (Intel "Smart" Technology) then you do not have to worry about Windows 8 on it. At least with all the problems it could have caused with UEFI activated.

Note that you actually need the `nvidia-313` for this card to work (As shown in the link I provided). I already tested that one with the `nvidia-310` and `nvidia-304` and had issues with it.

`lspci` will show all the PCI devices on your system. So it you do the following:

`lspci| grep NVIDIA`

and it shows something about NVIDIA, like in my case:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Then you are using the NVIDIA card. This can be changed in the BIOS if you want, but by default, motherboards first look for a PCI or AGP video card. If not found they go with the onboard one.

I also suggest (Since you have a new system) to run the following command: sudo `update-pciids`

This will update the list of PCI ID devices. Just in case not all PCI devices appear on the list (Very rare, only occurs on very new hardware).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but:

I followed the instructions in the link (and even one that page linked to) but to no avail. After typing `sudo apt-get install nvidia-313` the terminal responded, saying that the package `nvidia-313` does not exist. Is there anything I've forgotten or done wrong that may have lead to this response?

Comment: You need to add the PPA mentioned there. It is above the line that you just mentioned.

Comment: @user133717 did you add the PPA and test again?

Comment: I've managed to get the Nvidia 313 driver, but the issues still persist. (Sorry for the late reply, been sick)

Comment: @user133717 Same here buddy, been sick 4 days already. Just writing to ask if you have upgraded the system (apt-get update and upgrade) and ran the command dmesg to see if it said something about Nvidia problem or when connecting the mouse

Comment: After running dmesg in terminal, several of the lines mentioned 'IRQ #16'. A similar message appears on the blank boot-up screen, "disabling IRQ #16," I thought this was normal as its been there since I first used Ubuntu. After searching the net, it seems it could be causing the OS to slow, and is related to my sound card. In device manager (in Windows 8) it lists my 'sound, video and game controllers' as 'NVIDIA High Definition Audio' and 'Realtek High Definition Audio'.